# woocommerce: Show login / register form without account information

Tags: wordpress, forms, authentication, woocommerce

I want to show the woocommerce login and register page but without the options when an user is logged in.

In former versions you could use a shortcode but now you have to use [my_account]. When an user is logged in, he sees his account information.

Are there any hooks / functions to show the register and login forms?

Thanks
Maddin

Answer (score 1):

i know, the question is a little bit older...

Try this:

```
add_shortcode('woo-login', 'my_login');

function my_login() {
        if (is_user_logged_in()) {
         // Do what you want...
        } else {
            ob_start();
            echo '<div class="woocommerce">';
            wc_get_template('myaccount/form-login.php');
            echo '</div>';
            return ob_get_clean();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Although Oliver's code works, it's now missing a couple Woocommerce styles and subsequent JS that WP uses to render the form correctly. Perhaps they added these since the answer was posted. This snippet adds relevent `<body>` classes if the `woo-login` shortcode is used.

```
/**
 * Shortcode - Render Woocommerce login/register form
 **/
add_shortcode('woo-login', function() {

    if (is_user_logged_in()) {

    } else {
        ob_start();
        echo '<div class="woocommerce">';
        wc_get_template('myaccount/form-login.php');
        echo '</div>';

        return ob_get_clean();
    }
});


/**
 * Mitigate theme before render
 **/
add_action('template_redirect', function() {

    global $post;

    if (has_shortcode($post->post_content, 'woo-login')) {
        // Add Woocommerce body classes
        add_filter('body_class', function($body_classes) {
            $body_classes[] = 'woocommerce-account';
            $body_classes[] = 'woocommerce-page';

            return $body_classes;
        });
    }
});
```

Heres a link to the Gist: https://gist.github.com/dhaupin/7a5d429de5be0d623add58edad51b479