# How to Disable Woocommerce My Account Autodirect

Tags: woocommerce

I'd like to customize the Woocommerce login/register page using an editor plugin which requires you to be logged into the Wordpress Dashboard. The problem is Woocommerce directs to the My Account page if the user is logged in. Is there a snippet I could temporarily run that will tell Woocommerce to load the login/register page instead of the My Account page if the user is logged in?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution thanks to a reply Oliver Vogel made to someone else asking the same question here. Thanks Oliver! [This is Oliver's Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29125983/woocommerce-show-login-register-form-without-account-information/34686486#34686486)

For non-technical people like me who are trying to edit the Woocommerce Login / Register page while being logged into the Wordpress dashboard, insert this snippet into the functions.php file preferably with a nice plugin like Code Snippets. It will create a shortcode called [woo-login]. Create a new web page and add the [woo-login] shortcode to it and the Woo login page will open even when you are logged in.

```
add_shortcode('woo-login', 'my_login');

function my_login() {
    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
     ob_start();
        echo '<div class="woocommerce">';
        wc_get_template('myaccount/form-login.php');
        echo '</div>';
        return ob_get_clean();
    } else {
        ob_start();
        echo '<div class="woocommerce">';
        wc_get_template('myaccount/form-login.php');
        echo '</div>';
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
}
```